# How to group a second trace in Plotly (R) with the selections in first trace (to accomplish a single legend entry for each selection)?

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to map data from the 2020 and 2024 US Presidential elections based on days before vote, where selections exist in both the 2024 and 2020 elections. To that end, I want just a single legend entry for each candidate. The data frame I amusing has Prob_2024 and Prob_2020 on a candidate and days before vote basis.

[image: DF view]

The code I am currently working with is:

```
plot_3 <- plot_ly(
  data = total_3, type = 'scatter', mode= 'marker') %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~days_before_vote,
  y = ~ Prob_2020, color = ~selection_name)

plot_4 <- plot_3 %>%  layout(title = '2024 v 2020 US Election Trends',legend=list(title=list(text='Candidates:'))
         #,xaxis = list(dtick = "M1", tickformat="%b<br>%Y")
         ) %>%
  layout(
         xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed",
                      title = "\r\n Days Before Vote",
                      #standoff = 0,
                      zeroline = F,
                      zerolinewidth = 2,
                      gridcolor = 'ffff'),
         yaxis = list(title='Probability',
                      zeroline = F,
                      zerolinewidth = 2,
                      gridcolor = 'ffff'),
         legend = list(orientation = 'h', y=-.05,x=0),
         plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6'
        )

plot_4

plot_5 <- plot_4 %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~days_before_vote,
  y = ~ Prob_2024, color = ~selection_name)  %>% layout(yaxis = list(tickformat = ".%"))

plot_5
```

But it is producing double the legend view below:

[image: Plolty image]

I am trying to get the legend to group by candidate and have some  sort of tag for the 2020 vs 2024 difference. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: With a *picture* of the data instead of a reproducible question, I can offer suggestions but not a guaranteed solution. One option is to use a grouped legend. You can assign the candidate name to the same `legendgroup` and hide the legend for all but one trace associated with that candidate. For example, see [Grouped Legend](https://plotly.com/r/legend/) on Plotly's site. If you'd like a better answer - more specific to your code and data, make your question reproducible: Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).